# "you need to" vs. "you must"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

Let's suppose I want someone to give me more money.

Now I can say to that person:

"You need to give me more money."

or

"You must give me more money."

The request is meant to be somewhat harsh.

The question is not about alternative forms of the request, but specifically about the difference in meaning (if there is any) between the two forms.

Is there a the subtle difference between the two forms?
I have the impression that "you must" is a somewhat stronger request than "you need", but I'm really not sure.

Comment: You say you don't grasp the subtle difference between the two. But what makes you think there *is* a difference to be grasped? Syntactically, one difference is you can say *I **need you** to give me more money*, but it's not easy to incorporate ***must*** in such a variation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the useful edit. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You could say, "I need more money from you." Both of your examples are a little harsh (almost rude). Unless you are robbing a bank. ;-)

Comment: Firstly, 'need to' may be subject-or object-oriented. 'That's only a half of what our lawyers agreed: you need to give me more money.' // 'I can't afford the air fare dad; you need to give me more money.' 'Must' would normally be used in the 'subject is morally or otherwise obliged to' sense here, and probably sounds more forceful.

Comment: Yes, "must" is stronger. "You need to" implies that the other person has the need -- but it is *your* need, not his that you are addressing. (But do note FumbleFingers' excellent comment above, addressing a broader usage.) I agree this belongs on ELL, not here.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "English Language Learners", sorry if I posted on the wrong forum. All your comments were very helpful and confirmed the impression I had.